# MonoGame project quits unexpectedly when run

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, monogame

I'm new to MonoGame and C#, so I might be doing something stupid, but I can't figure out what is wrong with my project for the life of me.

`SharpEngine/SharpContext.cs`:

```cs
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using SharpEngine.Utils;

namespace SharpEngine
{
    public class SharpContext : Game
    {
        public Logger logger;

        public GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

        public SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        public SharpContext()
        {
            logger = new Logger();

            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            logger.Log("Initializing...", true);

            Window.Title = "Sharp Engine";

            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 720;
            graphics.ApplyChanges();

            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            base.Initialize();

            logger.Log("Initialized.", true);
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            base.Draw(gameTime);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
    }
}
```

`SharpGame/Main.cs`:

```cs
using System;
using SharpEngine;

namespace SharpGame
{
    class Game1 : SharpContext
    {
        public static Game1 game1;
        public Game1() : base()
        {
            Program.game1 = this;
            game1 = this;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static Game1 game1;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Game1 game = new Game1())
            {
                game.logger.enableVerbose();
                game.logger.Log("Starting up...", true);
                game.logger.Log("Calling SharpContext.Run()...", true);
                game.Run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the game is run, the only output is:

```
[ 9:56:13 AM Verbose Log       ]: Starting up...
[ 9:56:13 AM Verbose Log       ]: Calling SharpContext.Run()...
```

and then it immediately exits.

I'm clueless as to why this is happening.

I'm on Manjaro Linux.

If any more info is needed to help, just ask, and I'll provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I was using `MonoGame.Framework.Portable`, which is just headers. I feel dumb.